# jQuery jscrollpane track goes too far at bottom

Tags: jquery, tabs, jscrollpane, jquery-tools

I'm using jscrollpane in a jQuery Tools tab and have one last hill to climb, dish to wash, dog to walk - pick your own metaphor.

The page is here: http://bdbcreative.com/index3.htm#web-design.htm

If you drag the scroll bar track and go all the way to the bottom, you'll see that it goes about 25 to 30 pixels too far, past the end cap arrow. I've tried numerous solutions both in CSS and JavaScript, but nothing has worked out so far.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Best - Joe

Comment: @undefined: Aha! I see Perfect usage everywhere. Cool! :D

Comment: Boy, do I feel like a doofus. I never realized that was how you accepted answers. I kept trying to click the up widget and got a message that I didn't have 15 reputation points now. Sorry for being a bozo; I've gone back and accepted all the answers that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

What I noticed was

`.jspTrack` has the correct height  (around `525px`)

However, `.jspPane` has something like `550px`?

Also, seems to me like you should be calling the scroll bar plugin on an outer wrapper `div` since you scrollbar looks like its moving with the content.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I tried setting a height for .jspPane to 525px !important; but it didn't fix the issue. I also tried moving the class that calls the plugin out a div, but again no love.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by going into the jquery.jscrollpane.js file and adding 30 to the verticalTrackHeight variable on line 277. Kind of brute force, but it works.

Comment: @JoeLowery: Web development is full of hacks and workarounds if you ask me. Especially since one is expected to complete things in no time!

Comment: I totally agree. In fact, I wrote a book on it: CSS Hack and Filters. A little outdated now, but I really wrote it for myself, so I could find what I needed quickly and easily.